# add a variable value to a function python

Tags: python, parameters, parameter-passing

I have the following function:

```
modeliMLClean.reactions.ACLS.knock_out()
```

ACLS is a reaction and this function will knock out this reaction from the model. If I want to knout out another reaction, I just change the reaction name, for example:

```
modeliMLClean.reactions.XPPT.knock_out()
```

which will knock out the reaction XPPT.

What Im trying to do is that I have a list of reactions, Im iterating over the list and I want to replace the reaction name, something like this:

```
def ko(rx):
    modeliMLClean.reactions.rx.knock_out()

for x in zeroBoth:
    ko(x)
```

But when I do that, i think its getting only the rx value as rx, not as the reaction name as I need.
Do you know another way to give the parameter?

Comment: In general, use `geattr` when you don't have the literal name of an attribute to use as an identifier. `getattr(modeliMLClean.reactions, rx).knockout()`. This assumes that `zeroBoth` is a list of strings like `['ACLS', 'XPPT']`. If it isn't, you should update the question to be a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you can do so, It would be better to store the actual reaction into the array as opposed to a string, then iterate over it

```py
reactions = [modeliMLClean.reactions.ACLS, modeliMLClean.reactions.XPPT]

for reaction in reactions:
    reaction.knock_out()
```